# how to specify index of specific elements in each sublist of nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, nested

i have several nested lists, which are all permutations of each other within sublists:

```
x = [
['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]],
['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]],
[[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a'],
['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]
]
```

I want to select only those, which comply with this requirement: if sublists contains element 'd' in it, it must have index 0 in that sublist.
So among lists in x only

```
['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]
```

must be selected.
I tried this function:

```
def limitation(nested):
    result = []
    for i in nested:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            return limitation(i)
        else:
            if (i =='d' and nested.index(i) == 0):
                return nested

for i in x:
    print(limitation(i))
```

But the output is ['d', 'e'] instead of ['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]
]. How could i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative without the need to pass the root list each time.

```
def limitation(nested):
    for k, v in enumerate(nested):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            if limitation(v):
                return nested
        else:
            if (v == 'd' and k == 0):
                return nested

for i in x:
    if limitation(i):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to always pass the `root` element together with the `nested`.

```py
x = [
    ['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]],
    ['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]],
    [[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a'],
    ['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]
]

def limitation(root, nested, letter):
    result = []
    for i in nested:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            return limitation(root, i, letter)
        else:
            if (i == letter and nested.index(i) == 0):
                return root

result = list(filter(lambda a: a, [limitation(i, i, 'd') for i in x]))
print(result)
```

That will give you the result you need:

> ['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]

Comment: Not quite, you will get the full list (x) not the specific row

Comment: Got you. Fixed now.

Comment: yeah and also for example if its not only 'd' but 'b' and 'd' so it will be like  if (i in ['b', 'd'] and nested.index(i) == 0) it won't work considering both rules. So in this case it must bring nothing, however it will consider all four lists suitable

Comment: @EdZ hmm.. I don't see anything about 'b' in your question.

Comment: @dmigo yeah but obviously 'd' is a conditional variable and it might be any other string or multiple strings

Comment: @EdZ Ok, check it now. Is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

## I am new to python and my answer is a little verbose.  I am sure I am not making good use of the python language as I have yet to learn all the commands and options.  This accounts for string of different sizes.  So here goes a newbee approach:

```
x = [
    ['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]],
    [[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a'],
    ['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'dea']]]]],
    ['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]
]

def ck(pl, dlevel, dstring, mystr):
    if (pl == dlevel) and (str("'"+dstring.strip()+"'") == mystr.strip()) :
        return "match"
    return ""

def dlimit(dlist, dlevel, dstring):
    pl = 0
    mystr = ""
    for xl in dlist:
        for i in str(xl):
            if i == "[" :
                mystr = ck(pl, dlevel, dstring, mystr)
                pl += 1
            elif i == "]" :
                mystr = ck(pl, dlevel, dstring, mystr)
                pl -= 1

            elif i == ',' :
                mystr = ck(pl, dlevel, dstring, mystr)
            else:
                mystr += i

            if mystr == 'match':
                print(xl)



print ('a',1)
dlimit(x, 1, 'a')

print ('\ndea',5)
dlimit(x, 5, 'dea')
```